# What is "Ripa autem erat munita acutis sudibus sub aqua fixis ut sudes flumine tegerentur" in English?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

Right now, I have:

> Ripa autem erat munita acutis sudibus sub aqua fixis ut sudes flumine tegerentur

> But he had been protecting a sharp spear underwater"

I don't know how to do the rest.

Comment: Welcome to the site! How did you arrive at this translation? What part does the original cover? Is there something specifically that you struggle understanding? Where is the original text from? Editing more details into the question would improve it and make others more likely to answer.

Comment: Hint: *erat munita* does not mean "he had been protecting," it means "she had been protected" (or rather "it" in this case, *ripa*, the riverbank). *Sudibus* is ablative plural and agrees with *fixis*, "fastened."

Comment: @user9689: Is this from "Julius Caeser"? It helps to provide a reference, if possible.  The "...ut sudes flumine tegerentur." part = "...in order that the spikes were covered by the river.". It may fortify your confidence to know that the works of JC (Latin & English) are available, on the net, and are easy to find.

Comment: @tony Your intuition is right, it is based on [*De Bello Gallico* V 18,3](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0002%3Abook%3D5%3Achapter%3D18%3Asection%3D3). I say "based on" because it is quite heavily modified, presumably by a Latin teacher or textbook author. I assume the purpose of such modifications (besides simpler vocabulary etc.) is to prevent students from just looking up the translation online ...